# how to add scrollbar buttons to default cinnamon theme?

Tags: cinnamon

My installation of Cinnamon 2 on Ubuntu 13.10 has no up or down scrollbar buttons.

I've tried many suggestions such as [this one](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1226488), but none work.

How can up and down scrollbar buttons be added to the default theme?

(I can change themes but like the default theme and would like to know how to add scrollbar buttons to any theme)

Comment: Are you are referring to [this](http://www.digitalsociety.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/retire-scrollbar.png), not [this](http://joesteiger.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Screenshot-22.png)? :-s

Comment: @wilf Thank-you for looking wilf!  I have neither, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` look like this <sub>***(If the top line IS NOT THE SAME, just add the bit after `.scrollbar`)***</sub>:

```
@import url("resource:///org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-main.css");

.scrollbar {
-GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 1;
-GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 1;
-GtkRange-slider-width: 15;
-GtkRange-stepper-size: 20;
}
```

This worked for me - <sub>Thanks! :-)</sub>

You might need to do it to `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/gtk-dark.css` as well <sub>***(Again, If the top line IS NOT THE SAME, just add the bit after `.scrollbar`)***</sub>:

```
@import url("resource:///org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-main-dark.css");

.scrollbar {
-GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 1;
-GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 1;
-GtkRange-slider-width: 15;
-GtkRange-stepper-size: 20;
}
```

You need to change the gtk2.0 anyway, as that is used in Firefox etc -

so change this in`/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`:

```
GtkScrollbar::has-backward-stepper      = 0 
GtkScrollbar::has-forward-stepper       = 0
```

to:

```
GtkScrollbar::has-backward-stepper      = 1  
GtkScrollbar::has-forward-stepper       = 1
```

In Gnome, you can restart with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>r</kbd> - but logging out and logging in again sometimes works.

Comment: do you also know how to change the window title font color in the same adwaita theme?